# How to obtain the content of a pandas multilevel index entry?

Tags: python, pandas

I set up a pandas dataframes that besides my data stores the respective units with it using a MultiIndex like this:

```
Name    Relative_Pressure         Volume_STP
Unit                    -              ccm/g
Description          p/p0   
0                0.042691            29.3601
1                0.078319            30.3071
2                0.129529            31.1643
3                0.183355            31.8513
4                0.233435            32.3972
5                0.280847            32.8724
```

Now I can for example extract only the `Volume_STP` data by

```
Unit            ccm/g
Description 
0             29.3601
1             30.3071
2             31.1643
3             31.8513
4             32.3972
5             32.8724
```

With `.values` I can obtain a numpy array of the data. However how can I get the stored unit? I can't figure out what I need to do to receive the stored `ccm/g` string.

**EDIT: Added example how data frame is generated**

Let's say I have a string that looks like this:

```
                      Relative                                                  Volume @ STP
                      Pressure                                                         
                                                                                    cc/g

                         4.26910e-02                                                29.3601
                         7.83190e-02                                                30.3071
                         1.29529e-01                                                31.1643
                         1.83355e-01                                                31.8513
                         2.33435e-01                                                32.3972
                         2.80847e-01                                                32.8724
                         3.34769e-01                                                33.4049
                         3.79123e-01                                                33.8401
```

I then use this function:

```
def read_result(contents, columns, units, descr):
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(contents), skiprows=4, delim_whitespace=True,index_col=False,header=None)
    df.drop(df.index[-1], inplace=True)
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays((columns,  units, descr))
    df.columns = index
    df.columns.names = ['Name','Unit','Description']
    df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
    return df
```

like this

```
def isotherm(contents):
    columns = ['Relative_Pressure','Volume_STP']
    units = ['-','ccm/g']
    descr = ['p/p0','']
    df = read_result(contents, columns, units, descr)
    return df
```

to generate the DataFrame at the beginning of my question.

Comment: I have replaced the images by text snippets.

Comment: To make it a little easier, and so I can truly understand your dataframe structure, can you add coded to generate this dataframe?  You have a three level column multi-index with names ['Name','Unit','Description'] and the default range index for the dataframe "row" index?

Comment: @ScottBoston I added the code necessary to get to DataFrame at the beginning of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `df` has a MultiIndex as columns, `df.Volume_STP` is still a pandas DataFrame. So you can still access its `columns` attribute, and the relevant item will be at index 0 because the dataframe contains only 1 Series.

So, you can extract the names that way:

```
print(df.Volume_STP.columns[0])
```

which should give: `('ccm/g', '')`

At the end you extract the unit with `.colums[0][0]` and the description with `.columns[0][1]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
df.xs('Volume_STP', axis=1).columns.remove_unused_levels().get_level_values(0).tolist()[0]
```

Output:

```
'ccm/g'
```

Slice the dataframe from the 'Volume_STP' using `xs`, then select the columns remove the unused parts of the column headers, then get the value for the top most level of that slice which is the Units.  Convert to a list as select the first value.

Answer (score -1):

A generic way of accessing values on multi-index/columns is by using the `index.get_level_values` or `columns.get_level_values` functions of a data frame.

In your example, try `df.columns.get_level_values(1)` to access the second level of the multi-level column "Unit". If you have already selected a column, say "Volume_STP", then you have removed the top level and in this case, your units would be in the 0th level.